# Rules for manipulating differential/ Leibniz notation?

Tags: calculus

What are the rules on manipulating Leibniz Notation?

dy/dt  = -(y-3)/2

Can I treat it like a fraction and do this?
dy = -(y-3)/2 dt

can I "convert" the dy into a derivative?

(dy/dt)(1/(y-3)) = -1/2
->  d/dt ln|y-3| = -1/2

Where can i find more information on how to manipulate these infinitesimals?

Answer (score 0):

These rules are shortcuts derived from your everyday rules of calculus.  For instance:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y)$$

Integrate with respect to $t$ to get $\int dy = \int f(y) dt$, or in other words "$dy = f(y) dt$" which means basically $dy$ can be replaced by $f(y)dt$ in an integeral.